# ESLint error - logical operator ill-formed in ngif?

Tags: angular, typescript-eslint

I'm running into an eslint build error but I can't determine which lint rule is blocking it...

```
<div class="checkbox-info" title="{{ checkboxDescription }}" *ngIf="checkboxDescription && hasToggle">
```

Error: "attribute value contains an ill-formed escape sequence: &&"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `htmllint` error.

You'll have to disable it, it's not compatible with angular templates.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot there was an htmllint running as well! The rule I had to toggle was `spec-char-escape`.